# Algorithm: Find an order and compare each value in two arrays with same length

Tags: arrays, algorithm, compare

We are assuming that there are two arrays **a[.]** and **b[.]** with same length n and designing an function that will return **true** if we could find an order that make

```
a[0]>b[0], a[1]>b[1], a[2]>b[2] ... a[n-1]>b[n-1]
```

otherwise return **false**

(e.g. `{7,9,4},{7,6,3}` pair has a item order of `{7,9,4} & {6,7,3}` that matches the condition, while `{7,9,4,5},{7,6,3,5}` pair has no order like that).

NB: There is no need to print the order, just return **true** or **false**.

NB2: Please make the algorithm as eﬃcient as you can (O(n) or less?)

Thank you all!

Comment: Please explain your comparison logic, `e.g. {7,9,4} vs {7,6,3} have an order that {7,9,4} vs {6,7,3} while {7,9,4,5} vs {7,6,3,5} have no order like that)`

Comment: @mayankbisht, thanks for your reminding, what I mean is as for  {7,9,4} vs {6,7,3}, we could reorder them like {**7**,_9_,4} vs {**6**,_7_,3} that **7>6**, _9>7_, 4>3 while as for {7,9,4,**5**} vs {7,6,3,**5**} there is no order like that because 9>7, 7>6, 4>3, but 5 is not greater than 5.    Have I made myself clear?

Answer (score 0):

First sort the arrays, if it doesn't satisfy your need, no other order will. Hope you can code it yourself (this seems like your homework). 
Can be O(nlogn).

#### Edit:

Or don't sort! Just select the maximums for each iteration and break/return as soon as the condition fails. That way, you don't have to sort all the way.
 But this is O(n2).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no, it's not my homework. In my way of thinking, I could sort them firstly, then compare, that is the complexity depends on the sorting algorithm, maybe O(n log n) for QKSORT, or O(n) for counting sort, but I think it has some limiting conditions and might be more efficient without sorting. Maybe I think too much :)

Comment: If it's not your homework, that's good :D edited to minimize the complexity.

Comment: Is your solution's complexity O(n^2)? BTW, thanks for your polishing the description :D.

Comment: Yes it is. If you can utilize an efficient sorting algorithm O(nlogn), and sorted pair comparison is O(n), so that is still much better than iterating O(n2).